# How Can I Fix rtl text labeling in Mapbox Studio?

Tags: labeling, style, mapbox, mapbox-studio

I'm new in [**Mapbox Studio**](https://www.mapbox.com/studio). My language is **[Persian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_language)**. I published new map at [here](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/itsmemm/cirq2801y002xj8nkhcmem2t5.html?title=true&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiaXRzbWVtbSIsImEiOiJjaXJxMGVrYzkwMGF4aHVuaHJzNXVjeTI5In0._G0-KRSQMwTLPfKpxrqrMg#14.05/35.6886/51.4412). When I use local language for label locations, it show as follow:

[image: 4]]

How Can I Fix rtl text labeling in [Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/studio)?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but after some research I found the following page and issue. Maybe you will find some answers there: https://www.mapbox.com/blog/maps-in-your-language/ and https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/1259

Comment: looks like rtl support for MapBox-GL is being tracked in this issue: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl/issues/4

Comment: In mapbox studio v1 is supported, But in new version its not supported yet.

Comment: Is "rtl" right-to-left or something else?  I don't read Persian so to me it is not clear what is wrong in your graphic.

Comment: @PolyGeo yes it's a `rtl` language.